# Could it be theorically posible "cut off" a piece of space-time?

Tags: spacetime, spacetime-dimensions

I know I may not have an accurate idea of what are the properties of space-time, but here is the idea:
By doing an analogy with moving from 2 to 3 dimensions, I have been wondering if in theory it would be possible to "cut off" a piece of space-time ? And that in order to move it, and "stack" it with another, which would with (my) stupid logic allow us 3 dimensional object to move into a 4th dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I do not quite follow your analogy, there are a few things that can be said about mutilating spacetime in general. To be very non-technical and a little casual...

Firstly, the fundamental idea of spacetime is that it is the arena of physics: within a spacetime effects propagate from place to place through time and *typically* if two places A & B are in causal contact, then A can affect B and B can affect A. An exception to this is when, say, B is behind a horizon, e.g. a black hole's event horizon, then A can affect B but B cannot affect A (because all signals, even light, are trapped behind the horizon).

If one could cut off a piece of spacetime, spacetime would be "disjoint" - there would be *two spacetimes* that have no causal connection to each other.

Most interesting perhaps is recent work connecting quantum mechanics and classical spacetime theories; Mark Van Ramsdonk (MVR) has argued that it is the intrinsic connection of entanglement that "holds space together" and that if a region of spacetime *could* be completely disentangled from the rest, it would separate (more technically, but still imprecisely, entanglement dictates the metric which determines how distance is calculated - no entanglement = "infinite" distance).

MVR's work was, I believe, a significant input to the idea $ER=EPR\ ^{*}$, i.e.  Einstein-Rosen = Einstein-Rosen-Podolsky, of Maldacena & Susskind that entanglement (the EPR part, after a famous thought experiment in quantum mechanics due to these three) between two things is equivalent to the existence of a (non-traversable) wormhole between them (the ER part, after the Einstein-Rosen "bridge" that we now consider a kind of wormhole).

All this is however tricky since in classical general relativity spacetime cannot "evolve" (the development of the manifold according to Einstein's equations) tears/rips although it *can* develop so-called singularities, such as at the "centre" of a black hole, where the curvature can become infinite - which is another way of saying the theory breaks down at such a point. But, to think of a singularity as a literal puncture in spacetime is at best an analogy.

As for the "stacking", mathematical physicists often consider constructions of spacetime by cutting and pasting mathematical objects called manifolds in order to investigate how cause and effect works in the resulting spacetime so that they can consider whether *our* spacetime could be of that kind (by comparing theory with observation), but it's important to realise that they are creating a foundation within which they will *then* apply physics, so the rules of physics don't apply to the construction process itself.

$\ ^{*}$ Physicists' (?Susskind) joke: from which, by basic algebra it follows that Podolsky ($P$) $=1$ (Unless, I suppose, $E, P, R$ are matrices or some other complex mathematical objects :)

Comment: Before anywthing, thx a lot for your answer
Oh sorry I forgot to develop it
I was thinking about - for instance - a world in a paper sheet. The only think I could think about in order to somehow reach the 3rd dimension would be to cut off a part of it and stack it somewhere else.
But now that you said it, it makes sense that if they managed to cut off a piece of paper it would just become a separate piece of space that they couldn't reach anymore right ? Same as you said with space-time.
So yes stacking space-time is too abstract and improbable for now ah ah

Comment: No offense to Susskind, but spacetime holds together just fine in the absence of wormholes or even matter in general, no matter how weak the gravitational interaction is. This obsession to link two phenomena, from quantum mechanics and general relativity, that have absolutely nothing visible in common trough constructs that are not even known to exist in the one that has at least some theoretical accommodation for them is plain ridiculous. There is a valid question here, but it has nothing to do with gravity. What spacetime is is currently unanswered. Let's just admit that and move on.

Comment: @CuriousOne The fact that two of our most successful physical theories, QM & GR are fundamentally incompatible suggests a search for some theory that has both as approximations in the appropriate limits is not-unreasonable, and without starting ab initio, building on what is already known and seeking connections/reinterpretations is a very pragmatic way to start. That QM & GR have ~"nothing in common" *is* the motivation - surely, one says, there must be some commonality...

Comment: I fully agree and that is exactly what Susskind is not doing here. The brutal reuse of a failed idea (nobody takes wormholes seriously outside the scifi community) is intellectually fairly bankrupt IMHO. Just imagine Newton would have suggested that the Moon is hanging on a string...